# Does writing 'About me' section like this give me negative affective?

Tags: resume

Currently, in my CV, the first section is the About me section. It says like this (I'll reserve the format of the text):

> **Broad knowledge,** is what my friends proud of me.
>   **Never stop asking question,** is what my advisor values me.

I wonder if writing like this gives me any bad affective. Will the HR think that I'm a confident person, know exactly about me (which I want them to know), or just an arrogant one, self esteem and paranoid?

Please be frank. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to distract from your question but I wanted to at least mention this.  You did not indicate whether this is the actual content in your CV (written in English) or you just translated from your native language for the purposes of this question. If it is in an English-version of your CV, I'd suggest you work on the grammar as that would reflect negative on you more significantly than almost anything else.

Comment: There is no need to apologize me. I'm writing it in English. Do you mean that these two sentences are wrong in grammar or just focus on grammar in general?

Comment: The grammar is wrong.  You are missing prepositions in both phrases and your pluralization is not correct.  You may want to visit [ELL.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) to get a better opinion on how to write it as my grammar is not always the best.  However, I would probably write the first sentence as "Broad knowledge, is **why** my friends **are** proud of me." and the second as "Never stop asking question**s**, is what my advisor values in me."  (also note the advisor can also be spelled adviser and depending on what country you are dealing with, the prefered spelling may change).

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does this section say about your ability and fitness to meet the requirements of the position? If it says nothing, then you're wasting your time writing it, you're wasting space on your resume and you waste your prospective employer's time reading it.  In fact, lay off anything in your resume that does not convey your readiness and ability to do the job.

Replace the "About Me" section with a "Summary of Qualifications" section, which is much more relevant. And focus that section on how your qualifications meet your prospective employer's needs. Repeat this to yourself: "my employers don't hire me because they love me or because they like me, they hire me because they need me."

Employers rarely read your resume without reading your cover letter. One good way to stand out is to mention in your cover letter that you are pursuing an interest or area of interest of yours that just happens to push a hot button of theirs :) For example, if you are one of those who say that you love Python, that you are trying to be as close to being a crack Python programmer and that's how you got crazy about Machine Learning, your days as an unemployed individual are numbered :)

Comment: If I apply to a position require a lot of research, does this section meet the requirement?

Comment: @Ooker Which section are you referring to? Mention  your ability to do research in whatever area in the "Summary of Qualifications"

Comment: I mean the *About me* one. So, should I just say "I'm eager to learn and not afraid to ask questions" in the *Summary of Qualifications*? Is it too orthodox? I would like to make my CV a little impressive, though.

Comment: @Ooker Unfortunately, "I'm eager to learn and not afraid to ask questions" ranks right up there with "I work hard". Don't waste breath, time and space talking about what everyone else is doing and thinking, too. You don't stand out by saying you are just like everyone else :) When competing for a job, I assume that everyone I am competing against is hardworking, eager to learn and not afraid to ask questions. And that my task is to go up against them and win :)

Comment: @Ooker Thirty years ago, there was one student who showed up dressed in a suit at my informal Columbia School of Engineering Alumni/student dinner and telling the almumns that he is good with numbers. What's wrong with this picture? :)

Comment: To your first comment: you're right. That's why I use an unorthodox way to express that idea. At my first thought, I didn't mean to make it just like old wine in new bottle, but after discussing with you, I think it really is. If you have nothing new to say, you should say it in a different way. I have already mentioned my ability to research in the *Research Experience* section. I still don't know a better way to make my CV stand out.

Comment: In your second comment, I think the wrong in that picture is that he was trying to sell himself out, but eventually become ridiculous. I think the lesson is: be careful when you want to be a deviant, cause you can be a fool :0

Comment: @Ooker The kid was trying to sell himself as good with numbers in a hall that was packed with engineers :)

Comment: Ohh, that's so profound. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you so much. Finally I have a reason to give up my refractory :)

Comment: There are some occasions that I only need to send my CV and need not to attach cover letter with it. Should I still keep the "About me" section in such cases? I'll rewrite it if it's necessary.

Comment: Let's start with this link http://lifehacker.com/5909168/ditch-the-cover-letter-when-applying-for-a-new-job-no-one-reads-them-anyway This link basically says that even if the cover letter is automatically stripped off, it still might pay to show up at the interview with a copy of the cover letter. Back to your question: in this case, treat the "About me" section as the cover letter section - You've got to put that you are passionate about your field, the kind of work you have to do and what the company does that's relevant to you - you've got to put that info in writing somewhere :)

Comment: So something like "I love Python because it's clean, short and scientists love it"? I gradually get your idea. How many sentences like that should be included?

Comment: @Ooker Not quite You love Python for what you can do with it - and continuously playing with Python to be better at it is how you got into Big Data and Machine Learning. Bang, two hot spots for the employer! :)

Comment: Very nice. I owe you a beer :)